# Azure Pipelines: How to I pass additional variables as part of template parameters

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, cicd

I have a variables.yml file and I call that in a pipeline with additional variables

pipeline.yml

```
name: xxx

parameters:
  - name: car
    type: string
    default: toyota

variables:
  - template: ./variables.yaml
  - name: var1
    value: abc
  - name: value2
    value: 123

stages:
  - stage: abe
  - stage: 123
```

Now I my case is that I want to call the variables.yml file as part of template parameters including variables

pipeline-new:

```
trigger: abc-test
pool: cloud
extends:
  - template: /abc/123/test.yml
    parameters:
      varFile: './variables.yml'
      build: false
      scan: true
```

Now how do I pass var1 and var2 as part of template parameters to support variables.yml

As of now i hardcoded var1 and var2 in test.yml. But, I dont want to hardcode it but I wanted to pass them as part of template parameters.